# AWS AMI Cross Account Sharing with tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ami

I am trying to share ami's from source account A to target account B. In source account A the ami has some tags. While performing cross account sharing the tags are not flowing into ami to account B. I am aware of that tags are private and local to an aws account. Somehow I need to create the tags into target account B.

What are the best ways to create tags into target accounts? considering i have one source account and 50 target accounts to share ?